# How can I add a library to portable Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

To preface: Yes, I have indeed read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285986/using-java-library-in-eclipse). I tried it and it failed because of reasons I'll explain below. It's not a duplicate for the sole reason that the question linked is over three years old and, obviously, Eclispe has changed since then, and what once worked works no longer.

**TL;DR**: I tried that and it didn't work. What else can I do?

Anyway, my actual question is largely the same; I'm just looking for an updated answer. I couldn't find one on Google -- every reply I found was either for another IDE or as old as the previous question -- so might as well post it here.

I'm working on a project where, instead of using the `Date` and `Calendar` Java built-ins, I want to use Joda-time. I've heard lots of wonderful things about it and, from my own experience, it seems quite nice. However, because I'm a student, I want to be able to work on this both in school and at home, which means I need to make it portable. Again because I'm a student, I can't install Java 8 and use their new built-in classes which do the same thing. Therefore, I need a way to portably install a library.

However, when I change computers, the drive letter changes, and so just adding it as an external jar in the flash drive won't work. I tried adding it as a normal jar, as suggested in the previous question, but that failed because even though my `libs` folder is in the same directory as the `src` folder, as it says, it doesn't appear in the menu.

[image: Add JARs menu]
 The `Add JARs...` menu

[image: File structure]
 My file structure (library is inside `joda-time-2.5`)

Next, I tried manually editing the `.CLASSPATH` file. I did a bit of testing to see how it worked, then tried changing the absolute path to a relative one. However, that still failed, as when I changed computers it told me it couldn't find the library, though the relative paths are unchanged. To clarify, I changed the equivalent of this:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="F:/.../ProjOrg/libs/joda-time-2.5/joda-time-2.5.jar"/>
```

to this:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/joda-time-2.5/joda-time-2.5.jar"/>
```

and it still threw an error when I moved computers, though it worked fine on the first machine.

Is there a way I can import or otherwise link the Joda-time library to my portable Eclipse so I don't need to do anything when I move PCs? Alternatively, is there a way I can get Java 8 onto my flash drive so I don't have to worry about it?

Comment: The answer to the linked question is correct and works definitely. You must be doing something wrong. If you click on `Add JARs...` in the `Java Build Path`=>`Libraries` tab, you should be able to select any file inside your project.

Comment: @AndréStannek No, I am not doing anything wrong. I can guarantee you that. I click on `Add JARs...` and it shows a dialog where only certain files and folders are shown. I'll post a screenshot as soon as GIMP finishes downloading as proof.

Comment: Please also post a screenshot of your project structure that shows where you put the jar file.

Comment: @AndréStannek http://i62.tinypic.com/10mnbip.png shows the file structure. Notice that the `libs` file which you claimed would exist does not. I also accidentally cropped out the "src" folder though by accident. http://i60.tinypic.com/2u6ijqf.png is what Eclipse shows in its "Add JARs..." dialog.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be right. The second screenshot is missing the src folder. I suspect you are working on two entirely different folders.

Comment: I meant the first screenshot. The one from the file browser ;-)

Comment: Like I said, I accidentally cropped out the `src` folder since it appears below `libs`. I was a bit rushed since my free had just ended and I had to get to class. I'll fix it now.

Comment: @AndréStannek Alright, updated image is in the question now. As it says, the jarfile is inside of `joda-time-2.5`.

Comment: Allright, that's strange indeed. Does the lib folder appear inside Eclipse in the project and/or navigator view? If not try a refresh on the project.

Comment: Ah, that did it. I didn't realize that it wouldn't autorefresh -- since I was regularly closing and opening it, I assumed that it would refresh then. Whoops.

Comment: Glad it finally worked. I'll try and put this into an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @AndréStannek How is the answer coming? If you'd like I can put it up.

Comment: Sorry, something came up unexpectedly yesterday. Have done it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the project needed a refresh.

If you copy files into your project using and external file browser, Eclipse doesn't see those new files automatically. One should keep this in mind. A simple refresh often solves seemingly unexplainable errors regarding missing files. Happens to me a lot.

I would have expected that the "Add JARs..." dialog reads directly from the file system but it seems to use the project content known in the workspace at that time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create some variable to declare the *ROOT* of your path and then add this *ROOT* to the relative path where the library can be found.  For example:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="*ROOT*/.../yourlibrary.jar" />
```

To create the variable, you have to go to ***Java*** --> ***Build Path*** --> ***Classpath Variables***, and there you have to define that the *ROOT* is.  Obviously, *ROOT* is the part that changes by location.

**UPDATE**:

In response to the comment added by the OP, I am not sure if what you are asking is doable outside of creating some sort installation script.  You can check in the *.classpath* file in your CM repository just like you would any other project file, so that every developer gets the same *.classpath* file.

The problem is that a user can install a library wherever he/she wants and there is no much you can do about it. Also, if you have library in a server, you can map that network drive differently.

I think I did something similar (although not as restrictive), where we created an *ECLIPSE_HOME* environment variable, and then provided a simple installer (a batch file) to install Eclipse with some plugins.  You can have a master copy of the Eclipse install in a zip file with the JAR file in it, and you could run the script to set this environment variable and unzip Eclipse in the same location for all users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was asking for a way that didn't require me to change something for every computer. While this is helpful and interesting, it's not what I was looking for. I'm going to clarify that in the question.

Comment: ...It appears I clarified badly. I know where the file is going to end up relative to the project -- in fact, except for the drive letter, the absolute path remains unchanged. My bad.

Comment: I think the answer will still be the same: You are going to need some sort of script to do what you want.